# Tex compiler where \\ is not required

Tags: line-breaking

I wrote a lot of tex notes in document form, and manually linebreaked, instead of using `\\`. It is a lot of text and I would like to compile them without having to add a `\\` after every line... What should I do?

Comment: use `\obeylines` ? (although it is normally very rare to use `\\ ` at all in text why do you need manual linebreaking?)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa\\
bbb\\
ccc


or

aaa

bbb

ccc


or

{\obeylines
aaa
bbb
ccc
}

\end{document}
```